# Is it possible to have a test on tensor size inside a tensorflow tf.function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def my_func(x):
    res = x[0] + x[1]
    if tf.size(x) == 3:
        res += x[2]
    return res
print(my_func(tf.ones((3,))))
print(my_func(tf.ones((2,))))
```

This gives the following error for the second call:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-316b7b94c951> in <module>
      8     return res
      9 print(my_func(tf.ones((3,))))
---> 10 print(my_func(tf.ones((2,))))

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    604       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    605       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 606       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    607       if self._created_variables:
    608         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2360     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   2361     with self._lock:
-> 2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2364 

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2701 
   2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2591             arg_names=arg_names,
   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2594         self._function_attributes,
   2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    976                                           converted_func)
    977 
--> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    979 
    980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    437         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    441 

~/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-1-316b7b94c951>:7 my_func  *
        res += x[2]
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:898 _slice_helper
        name=name)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:1064 strided_slice
        shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:9535 strided_slice
        shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py:742 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py:595 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:3322 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1786 __init__
        control_input_ops)
    /home/zaccharie/workspace/tfkbnufft/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1622 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: slice index 2 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [2], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <2>, input[2] = <3>, input[3] = <1>.
```

This is just a toy example to understand the problem I am facing. I know I could use `reduce_sum` to do more or less this function.
Basically in my real use case I want to be able to test on a tensor size so it's the main point.

The `tf` version I am using is 2.1. Python is 3.6.8.

Note that without the `tf.function` decorator, in eager mode, the function works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read more on the [limitations of autograph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#autograph-reference).
In particular in [this section](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#mixing-dynamic-computations-and-static-shapes):

> Because tf.shape always evaluates to a Tensor, the if statement above is converted by AutoGraph into a tf.cond, which performs static shape verification of both branches.

I guess this is also true for `tf.size`. The fix they provide is the following:

```py
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,)),))
```

N.B: don't forget the second comma, there is a typo in the docs.

This indeed fixed my problem.